# Word Online can't delete existing Content Control

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

My Word add-in on desktop app adds content controls (and corresponding named bindings), but when I open the same file using Word Online, the add-in first deletes all bindings (successfully, confirmed via breakpoint) then attempts to delete all content controls. However, it throws an error trying to deleting any content controls.

Source code:
[image: Source code in add-in attempting to delete CC]

The error:

[image]

Other variables in scope:

[image]

Any idea why Word Online can't delete these previously created content controls? The same add-in on desktop app succeeds, even between different machines running Word.

Comment: Can you delete a single CC, that is, not in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Word Online only supports content controls if the following conditions are met:
1) The content controls are of type Rich Text Content Control
2) The content controls cannotDelete property is false
3) The content controls are in fully-supported paragraphs, which means that no other features existing in the paragraph that are not supported in Word Online, such as fields, unsupported content controls, tab keys in the content controls, or content controls for a whole table cell, etc. You can verify this by trying to edit the content control via UI to see if it's possible.

Could you double check whether some of these conditions are not met? If all conditions are met but it still fails, please send a sample document with the issues so that we can do further investigation. Thanks.

Comment: I can edit the content controls in the Word Online UI. Does this test verify the 3 criteria you listed are met?